# Native Base Picker returning: "Maximum update depth exceeded"

Tags: react-native, redux, native-base

When I include the Picker tag from native base in my component, I get the error:

"Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

```
...
import {
  Item, ListItem, Input, Form, Body, CardItem,
  Picker, Icon, CheckBox, Button, Card
} from 'native-base';
import Octicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUnits } from '../../actions';

...

class MyComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedUnit: undefined,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUnits();
  }

  onChangeUnit = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedUnit: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Form>
          <Card>
            <CardItem>
              <Octicons active name="tools" size={18} />
              <Text style={styles.cardText}>   Units</Text>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
          <Item picker>
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              iosHeader="Select Unit"
              placeholder="Units"
              iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
              style={{ width: undefined }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedUnit}
              onValueChange={(text) => this.onChangeUnit(text)}
            >
            {Object.keys(this.props.units).map((key) => {
                return (
                  <Picker.Item
                    label={this.props.units[key]}
                    value={key}
                    key={key}
                  />
                );
            })}
            </Picker>
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ util }) => {
  const { error, units } = util;

  return { error, units };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getUnits
})(MyComp);
```

The Action getUnits is very simple (hardcode for now).

```
export const getUnits = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const units = {
        "1": "101",
        "2": "102",
        "3": "103",
        "4": "104",
    };
    dispatch({
      type: GET_UNITS,
      payload: units
    });
  };
};
```

If I remove the Picker, it works. Why is returning the error?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like an issue with the latest release. Downgrade to 2.12.1 or wait for the next release as it's been fixed. https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2810

Comment: What do I should to downgrade? Native Base?

Comment: The upgrade has been released, you're likely on 2.13.0, upgrade to 2.13.1

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Just spent like 4 hours banging my head on this. Thanks!